# Google Maps retina map markers do not display correctly on Android Jellybean native browser

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, android-4.2-jelly-bean

The map marker is scaled and cropped incorrectly when using optimized: false. I have tested on several android devices and iphones.

I am running into an issue that only seems to affect the native browser on Android Jelly Bean, ICS and below on Android and all iPhones display the map marker correctly. Chrome on Android Jelly Bean also displays correctly.

I have code samples [optimized false](http://www.nonpixel.com/gmap/mapmarker.html) and [optimized true](http://www.nonpixel.com/gmap/mapmarker-optimized.html).

A screen shot of how it appears when optimized is set to false is located here: 
nonpixel.com/gmap/screenshot.png (sorry I am limited to two hyperlinks per post)

The closest related question that I have found is 9208916 (again sorry for no link), but the solution did not work.

A few other observations:

- when adding animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP, the map marker animates in at the correct size, but it appears to go behind the larger, incorrectly sized marker.
- The map marker shadow displays correctly
- The map tiles themselves initially load in "retinafied" but then switch out to the optimized, blurry tiles (which you can see in the screen cap listed above)

Comment: If the question is [Android] then it is not [google-maps-api-3]